# Specific object moves too much when moving it

Tags: objects

I have downloaded an .obj model of a bottle, and after importing it into blender, it behaves weirdly..(it's fine in edit mode) I have tried applying transforms. Here is comparison to object that is fine.
Moving it is truly frustrating.

[image: gif of the issue]
sry for bad gif quality had to make it less than 2mib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the origin point of the object to itself
If that doesn't help, also try resetting its scale and location.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about the origin. All fine and dandy now :)